# Elasticsearch does not fuzzy

Tags: elasticsearch

I struggle to perform a [fuzzy search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html) with Elasticsearch 7.10.

My request is the following:

```json
{
  "size": 5,
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "fuzzy": {
      "name": {
        "value": "P2",
        "fuzziness": "AUTO",
        "prefix_length": 0,
        "max_expansions": 50
      }
    }
  },
  "track_scores": false
}
```

While I have a record looking like:

```json
{
  "bookId": "book-2",
  "name": "Programming #2",
  "entries": 36
}
```

The `name` is declared as `{type: "text", fielddata: true}`, and, despite that, I have no result. Can you give me a hint regarding my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From docs:

> Returns documents that contain terms similar to the search term, as
> measured by a [Levenshtein edit
> distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).
>
> An edit distance is the number of one-character changes needed to turn
> one term into another. These changes can include:
>
> - Changing a character (**b**ox → **f**ox)
> - Removing a character (**b**lack → lack)
> - Inserting a character (sic → sic**k**)
> - Transposing two adjacent characters (**ac**t → **ca**t)

Your query `"P2"` doesn't match any of these cases. You might achieve this kind of behavior by changing source data or implementing analyzers that handle these kinds of use cases.